# Convertir Porciones de Cadenas a Mayúsculas

Tags: java

¿Cómo puedo convertir ya sea a mayúsculas o minúsculas sólo porciones de oraciones de una cadena? Específicamente, delimitadas por signos como `¿?`, `¡!`, o en el caso del inglés, cuando llevan solamente un `?` o `!` al final. Es decir, si tengo esta frase: `"Esta es una oración y, ¡quiero ser mayúscula!"` convertirla a `"Esta es una oración y, ¡QUIERO SER MAYÚSCULA!"`, o en inglés, `"This is a sentence, I want to be capitalized!"` convertir a `"This is a sentence, I WANT TO BE CAPITALIZED!"`. Sé usar más o menos la función `Character.toUpperCase()`, pero no sé cómo ser específico en las delimitaciones como los casos mencionados. Aprecio cualquier ayuda. Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te doy la solución mediante un método normal estático:

en tu método main:

```
String frase = "Buenas ¡esta es! una fr¡a!e";

String fraseFinal = convierteMayusculas(frase);

System.out.println(fraseFinal);
```

tu método:

```
public static String convierteMayusculas(String cadena){

    int indiceInicio = -1;
    int indiceFinal = -1;
    char caracter;
    String auxiliar = "";
    boolean encontrado = false;

    for(int i = 0; i < cadena.length(); i++){
        caracter = cadena.charAt(i);

        if(caracter == '¡'){
            indiceInicio = i;
            encontrado = true;
        } else if(caracter == '!' && indiceInicio != -1){
            indiceFinal = i;
        } 
        if(encontrado){
            auxiliar += caracter;
            if(indiceInicio != -1 && indiceFinal != -1){
                cadena = cadena.replace(auxiliar, auxiliar.toUpperCase());
                indiceInicio = -1;
                indiceFinal = -1;
                encontrado = false;
                auxiliar = "";
            }
        }
    }
    return cadena;
}
```

La salida del programa será:

```
Buenas ¡ESTA ES! una fr¡A!e
```

Como puedes ver la segunda cadena entre exclamaciones también se pone en mayúsculas y ademas las 'a' que no están entre exclamaciones no se ponen en mayúscula.

Puedes cambiar las exclamaciones por interrogaciones y funcionará igual, si quieres que los delimitadores sean idénticos, por ejemplo algo entre \ y \ puedes hacer un contador de cuantas veces aparece la \ desde su primera aparición, cuando el contador sea 2, haces el replace().

En cualquier caso si los delimitadores son distintos ie. !¡ y ¿?, este método te vale, cambias las exclamaciones por sus respectivas interrogaciones y funcionará igual.

Comment: Muchas gracias, @Reductor! Era precisamente lo que andaba buscando. De aquí ya puedo seguir sacando las diferentes variantes. Gracias una vez más.

Comment: De nada!, un saludo

Comment: Esta propuesta no soluciona el tema del inglés, siempre buscas el inicio de exclamación. Para el tema del inglés también no habría que recorrer hacia atrás la cadena guardando la posición de cierre de exclamación hasta la coma o hasta la apertura de exclamación?

Comment: Mr.Munoz he actualizado el código para ahorrar una linea en la que sumaba la cadena entre exclamaciones, y solo la uso una vez, ademas he añadido una condición al  if de la condición de la exclamación de cierre para que no lo considere a no ser que haya encontrado una exclamación de apertura antes, son nada 2 lineas.

Comment: Pablo Simon DiEstefano esta pregunta no esta orientada a la funcionalidad en el idioma inglés, si lees lo que pregunta verás que el siempre consideraba el español, pues pedía signo de apertura y de cierre, si quieres hacerlo en inglés, no tienes que recorrer hacia atrás ni nada, es tan facil como recorrer normalmente, añadiendo todos los caracteres que vayas recorriendo a tu auxiliar y cuando encuentres un signo de exclamación tal que así: '!', ese auxiliar es el que conviertes a mayúscula, cuando lo encuentres reseteas tu booleano encontrado a false y ya.

Answer (score 2):

Utilizando StringTokenizer.

Por ejemplo, tienes el siguiente String.

```
String texto = "hoy/esundia/especial";
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(texto, "/");
while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
     System.out.println(st.nextToken());
}
```

Esto te devolverá las siguientes cadenas:

- "hola"
- "esundia"
- "especial"

De la misma manera puedes sacar partes de la cadena con cualquier delimitador, ya sea '¿' , '?' o '!'